# get customized array format in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, php-5.3

I have table name with TEST
**id name_id name**
1   11      one
2   11      two
3   12      three
4   12      four
5   13      five

i need out put like follows with single query without foreach loop.

array(
      [11] => Array
        (
            [TEST] => Array
                (
                    [name] => one
                )

```
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [TEST] => Array
            (
                [name] => two
            )

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [TEST] => Array
            (
                [name] => three
            )

    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [TEST] => Array
            (
                [name] => four
            )

    )
 [13] => Array
    (
        [TEST] => Array
            (
                [name] => five
            )

    ));
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you get the data from the db currently

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the id with set::combine.

```
$data = set::combine(
    $this->TEST->find('all', array('fields' => array('name'))),
    '{n}.TEST.id',
    '{n}.TEST'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response thanpa.But i need to get all fields with that key.This is showing only one record per distinct key